# Docker compsoe not works the sama as docker run

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I run my ELK by docker run works fine, but when I run by docker-compose logs are sent to logstash very slow and not stable.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
    elasticsearch:
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.0
        ports:
            - 9200:9200
            - 9300:9300
        environment:
          - discovery.type=single-node

    kibana:
        image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.6.0
        links:
          - elasticsearch
        ports:
          - 5601:5601

    logstash:
        image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.6.0
        links:
          - elasticsearch
        ports:
          - 5044:5044
        volumes:
          - ./logstash/config/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
          - ./logstash/config:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/
```

run by docker run

```
docker run -d -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.
```

```
docker run -d --link edcf2406addf:elasticsearch -p 5601:5601 docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.6.0
```

```
docker run --link edcf2406addf:elasticsearch -v /var/www/logstash/config/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml -v /var/www/logstash/config:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/ -p 5044:5044 docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.6.0
```

I would like to use docker-compose but something not works fine. Could someone help me configuring docker-compose properly?

docker-compose version 1.21.0-rc1
Docker version 19.03.5

Thanks

Comment: Your compose commands and the plain docker commands look identical. Are you sure the config files are found and correctly configured locally?

Comment: Yes, the configuration is ok because if will be no ok ELK won't be work, but work very slowly and not stable

Comment: @DannyB as I see when run by docker-compose some logs appears:

elasticsearch_1  | {"type": "deprecation", "timestamp": "2020-04-23T12:14:46,194Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.d.a.b.BulkRequestParser", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "d4100327fd91", "message": "[types removal] Specifying types in bulk requests is deprecated.", "cluster.uuid": "6GA4O8VpQNG2qPqqBELX9Q", "node.id": "EMErrJv1QIqNRuH0JlfdCg"  }